# jQuery .load() - What is the preferred path?

Tags: jquery

So I have a WordPress theme Laid Out like this:

wp-content/themes/themename/

and I'm loading javascript that exists in:

wp-content/themes/themename/library/js/script.js

my issue is I have a call in script.js that does this:

```
$("#message").load('text.html');
```

With text.html also in the js folder mentioned above, but text.html is not being loaded.

script.js is included by head.php in the wp-content/themes/themename/ folder.  I tried placing the file there, and it doesn't work.

The onlything that seems to work is if the put the url http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/themename/text.html in load as follows:

```
$("#message").load('http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/themename/text.html')
```

Is it possible to load() the file with a path and not a full domain?  The jQuery doc indicates that it is, however I just can't get it to work.

Comment: you need to load it relative to the current page, not the script. therefore, if the user is currently viewing `http://domain.com/index.php`, you'll have to reference it from the root.

Comment: Ah so I solved this on my own.  You don't have to use http://... full url, your first slash will be relative to domain.  So in my case:

    $("#message").load('/wp-content/themes/themename/text.html/text.html');

Is the equivalent while allowing the code to work agnostic to the domain.

Comment: correct, as long as that path remains correct.

Comment: Thanks Kevin couldn't have solved it without that perceptual fix. :D